# Octave's argv parses arguments space-separated, how to pass a multiple-word argument?

Tags: bash, parsing, octave, argv

When running the `test.sh` bash script

```
#!/bin/bash +x

./test.m $*
```

which calls the `test.m` GNU Octave executable script, in one of these ways:

```
./test.sh my argument
./test.sh "my argument"
./test.sh 'my argument'
```

`argv()` will always parse these two strings:

```
ans = 
{
  [1,1] = my
  [2,1] = argument
}
```

Is there a way to get both words in a single argument, without further processing the result? Or said in a different way, can the separating character be different from blank?

Interestingly, the bash itself does make a difference from the first call and the other two. `$1` will get both words in the latter case, and only 'my' in the first one.

Secondly, how it would be if arguments are stored in a variable before been sent to the Octave script:

```
#!/bin/bash +x

a="$@"

./test.m $a
```

this would give the same result, two words:

```
ans = 
{
  [1,1] = my
  [2,1] = argument
}
```

While using `./test.m "$a"`

```
#!/bin/bash +x

a="$@"

./test.m "$a"
```

will have the effect of passing a single string, including all the arguments: `./test.sh "my argument" other` will pack `my argument other` together:

```
ans = 
{
  [1,1] = my argument other
}
```

Comment: @Suever sorry, updated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to either surround the string with `""` or escape the spaces with `\` when invoking an octave script

```
./test.m "hello world"
./test.m hello\ world
```

The issue that you're having is due to the fact that you are invoking your octave script from within another bash script and *that* bash script isn't forwarding your properly-escaped strings on to the octave call since you're just using `$*` which is unquoted. If you only want your octave script to have a single input, you'll want to surround `$*` with `""`

```
#!bin/bash
./test.m "$*"
```

And call it using:

```
./test.sh "hello world"

{
  [1,1] = hello world
}
```

The more robust option, however, is to use `"$@"` which will forward all inputs appropriately and allow you to pass multiple multi-word arguments

```
#!/bin/bash
./test.m "$@"
```

And use it

```
./test.sh "hello world" "how are you"

{
  [1,1] = hello world
  [2,1] = how are you
}
```

**Update**

As pointed out by [@Benjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349764/octaves-argv-parses-arguments-space-separated-how-to-pass-a-multiple-word-argu/40349926?noredirect=1#comment67957118_40349926) mentioned, if you want to store the inputs, you'll want to store them in an array

```
a=("$@")
./test.m "${a[@]}"
```

Comment: `"$@"` does make it. But now, how it would be if the arguments are stored in a variable before actually calling the Octave script (question updated).

Comment: @nightcod3r Your update isn't clear in exactly what you're trying to do and why. Can you show the actual code? There is likely a much better way.

Comment: @nightcod3r You'd have to assign them to an array: `a=("$@")` and then use them with `"${a[@]}"`.